# Escape velocity of leaving the solar system vertically and horizontally

Tags: solar-system, escape-velocity

Is there a difference in the escape velocity when leaving the solar system?

a) Vertically (out of planetary plane, in a perpendicular direction to it)

b) Horizontally (in the planetary plane)

Comment: No homework questions.

Comment: The answer you got for your previous post also applies here. Don't think Solar system is special because you live here.

Comment: Indeed. It's the perfect duplicate of the previous question.

Comment: There is quite a difference in mass distributuon between a galaxy and a solar system.  E.g. a galaxy's gravitational field is not dominated by a single object near the barycenter.  If you think the questions are the same, you should explain why rather than state it as fact.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape while that may be your personal position, it is not an articulation of site policy. [Homework policy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/87/7982) and [I can't find this site's "homework policy" or find out how "suspected homework question askers" should be treated](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/473/7982) *and especially* [Stop the off-hand "this sounds like a homework question" comments that offer no guidance and raise false flags?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/762/7982)

Comment: @uhoh While bible-thumping may be your personal go-to, I think most of the community agrees that lazy, "solve this problem for me"-type questions are not welcome here. You at least should show some valiant effort before typing up a question as, after all, we are not a homework portal for undergrads.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape the only thing we can know about what "most of the community agrees" on is what's agreed-upon in meta. Apart from that people just make stuff up. In this case, "'solve this problem for me'-type questions" get downvoted for "does not show any research effort" https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbNvg.png That's quite different than a "homework question". And I've never thumped a book.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity works in all direction the same, and you cannot shield it. You need the same velocity wrt the barycenter to leave its influence, regardless of direction.

Comment: Temporary -1 because "Gravity works in all direction the same..." is not the basis of an answer here. "'Escape' means at least asymptotically reaches infinity where only the monopole term applies" is the key here.